# Can't post an answer on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I'm trying to post an answer to my own question [Query to find all views/charts owned or shared with a user in Dynamics 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671712/query-to-find-all-views-charts-owned-or-shared-with-a-user-in-dynamics-2013/26728588#26728588) but I keep getting 'an error occured' in a small red pop-up if I try to post the full text of my procedure . The proc is 70 line long - that's acceptable, right?

Comment: If all it states is that an error occurred, it’s a technical problem. See if the Network tab of your browser’s developer tools reveals any network errors.

Comment: No issue there - a json post with 200 reply...

Comment: Does the content of the reply yield any clues?

Comment: What _is_ the content of the response?

Comment: Your local network is almost certainly filtering on SQL, causing the connection to be terminated when you try to post.